# Windows 10 Creating recovery drive on 4gb usb stick

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I'm creating a windows 10 recovery drive onto a 4GB usb drive, however the requirement states, 'at least 4GB'. Should this be enough? Can I place this onto DVD instead?

Comment: The tool that create the recovery drive won't accept DVDs.  It doesn't have the capability to write data to a DVD.

Comment: To create recovery drive in DVD media, use the legacy tool (recdisc.exe)

Comment: @w32sh Or simply burn the Windows.iso to a DVD

Comment: @JW0914: Ok. Thanks for the info. Enabling the "Back up system files to the recovery drive" option (when creating the drive) makes the difference though. Enabling the option creates two .wim files that contain system files and the **current** registry hives. That's why I said Recovery drive has an additional purpose.

Comment: @w32sh I think we're referring to two separate things.  I thought you were referring to the Recovery partition on the HDD, which is what my previous comment is regarding, whereas I think you're referring to the USB drive as the Recovery drive.  I believe it's the latter, so I've deleted my prior comment =]

Comment: Yep. I was referring to the USB recovery drive. But, the recdisc.exe doesn't seem to create the .wim files; it may create a DVD with only the boot.wim and supporting files. So I stand corrected. The "Backup system files..." option is applicable only for Recovery Drive (USB), not DVD.

Comment: @w32sh When Microsoft released Windows 10, they made it more convenient for all to get access to the Windows install ISO for all currently supported Windows editions via the Windows Media Creator.  I personally prefer [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or [RMPrepUSB](https://www.rmprepusb.com/documents/release-2-0) to create a bootable USB and choose the option to _not_ have Media Creator create a bootable USB.  This results with it creating `Windows.iso` for whatever version of Windows the user chose.

Comment: @JW0914: Rufus doesn't always show the latest Windows 10 build in the list. See: https://imgur.com/a/PQyXesG ; that means I'll have to [slipstream](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/slipstream-windows-10-integrate-updates-setup-media-iso/) it with the latest SSU and CU and install Windows. Not a big deal, but.. just saying.

Secondly, I see that the WIM files in the USB recovery drive include your current registry hives, which, I suppose will be restored when you reinstall Windows using it. Have to test it out this week to know what are the things that are restored.

Comment: When creating a LiveUSB via a Windows ISO with Rufus, the user shouldn't be selecting any of the individual images contained within the `install.wim`... the entire ISO should simply be used to create the LiveUSB _(there's no benefit to doing so, as the new exported `install.wim` is not going to be significantly smaller in size)_.

Comment: @JW0914: Not sure if I put it correctly. I mean, Rufus is not showing the latest build in the listing. The current W10 build is 18362.267 whereas Rufus shows 18362.30.

Comment: And here are the things copied when you create a USB recovery drive, as per [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bare-metal-recovery). Windows Component Store, Installed drivers, Backup of preinstalled Windows apps, Provisioning packages containing preinstalled customizations (under C:\Recovery\Customizations)
Push-button Reset configuration XML and scripts (under C:\Recovery\OEM)

If that's true, then I find the preinstallation of drivers very useful so that I don't have to install them manually.

Comment: @JW0914: On the contrary, [this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) says "To reinstall Windows 10, select Advanced Options > Recover from a drive. This will remove your personal files, apps and drivers you installed, and changes you made to settings."

Wondering what's the point of backing up the drivers then. LOL :-)
FWIW

Comment: @w32sh Microsoft changed how Windows handles System Restore and Reset last year, where now, any drivers installed as of the last major update (biannually in Mar & Sep) are restored from `WinSxS`, which is where Windows maintains a copy of all system files and drivers, and is what `DISM` checks and `SFC` restores from.  A clean install is still sometimes necessary (such as to eliminate bloatware), which is why the Media Creation Tool still exists

Answer (score 0):

A 4GB USB stick will never provide 4GB worth of storage space.

I'm unsure the exact size of the WIM and boot/recovery files but they're often bigger than the average 4GB stick average capacity in total.

Comment: The recovery completed without errors. Recovery drive used space is 2.99GB and free space is 758MB. Total capacity 3.73GB.

Answer (score 0):

The USB requirement vary with your Windows version. If your are using Windows 10 32-bit than a 4 GB USB stick is sufficient. But for a Windows 10 64-bit system I will advice you to use a 8GB stick.

**Note:** Recovery drive feature only works with a USB stick.

If you want to use a DVD, then create a System Image instead.